# Fat-Free Framework + JQuery AJAX GET = no response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fat-free-framework

I have a mapped Fat-Free Framework class declared as follows in my `index.php`:

```
$f3->map('/user', 'User');
```

The `User` class looks like this:

```
<?php
class User {
  function __construct($f3) {
    $this->users = new \DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->db, 'users');
  }

  function get($f3) {
    return json_encode('Just some text');
  }

  function post($f3) {
    // There is tested, working code in here but I've omitted it for simplicity's sake
  }

  function put($f3) {
  }

  function delete() {
  }
}
```

I have my Javascript first loaded by app.js like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPage = $(location).attr('pathname'),
      requiredJS = document.createElement('script'),
  requiredJS.type = 'text/javascript';

  switch(currentPage) {
    case '/mypage':
      requiredJS.src = 'myscript.js';
      $('body').append(requiredJS);
      break;
    // more cases...
  }
});
```

Then my simple AJAX call in `mypage.js` looks like this:

```
$.get('/user', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

When I go to the `/mypage` route, I get only an empty string in my console.  Why is this happening?  Where am I messing up?

Comment: try using `return json_encode(array('Just some text'));`

Comment: I tried that and still I get nothing, but thanks for the suggestion.  It appears that even when I put debug code in my `get` function, the function isn't even firing.

Comment: You should echo the result: `echo json_encode(array('Just some text'));`

Comment: That's it!  Please post this as the answer if you want the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should echo the result:

```
echo json_encode(array('Just some text'));
```